# Problems with low vcore voltage on Supermicro

Tags: bios, supermicro

Strange problem with Supermicro MB X9SCA-F - after BIOS update to 2.0a version, I got following messages in event log:
Critical - vcore low voltage

And the second problem is that BIOS time & date is not saved after reboot.

Please help.

Answer (score 2):

I dont know whether your problems have been solved or not. If not, then have tried to
see the log files from IPMI GUI? Any reason why you upgraded the BIOS? 
There is a bug in 2.0a version and you should upgrade it to R 2.0b.
New software is available at:
http://www.supermicro.nl/products/motherboard/Xeon/C202_C204/X9SCA-F.cfm
Regards